# In what namespace is FileOutputStream found

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm building a Console application in VS2010 ASP.NET C# using iTextSharp ver 5.5.2. I have all of the DLLs in the iTextSharp distribution referenced and have the following Using statements:

```
using System;  
using System.IO;  
using System.Net;  
using System.Web;  
using iTextSharp.text;  
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;  
using iTextSharp.tool.xml;
```

I'm looking at an iTextSupport.com posting as an example for the application that contains the following code segment:

```
Document document = new Document();

PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("results/loremipsum.pdf"));

document.open();
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, new FileInputStream("/html/loremipsum.html"));
document.close();
```

On the second line, creating an instance of a PDFWriter, appears the instantiation of "new FileOutputStream" which is throwing an error indicating that a Using statement or a Reference is required. Searching for FileOutputStream in the object browser for both my application AND .NET Framework 4 return no results.

Where is the class containing FileOutputStream to be found?

Comment: Here did you find this sample code?Maybe you mean FileStream ?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you've looked at some Java examples, there's no such beast as a FileOutputStream in .NET. In .NET you could use a [`System.IO.FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Document document = new Document();
using (var output = File.Create("results/loremipsum.pdf"))
using (var input = File.Open("html/loremipsum.html"))
{
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
    document.Open();
    XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, input);
    document.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use httpcontext.current.response.writeoutputstream